# Terraform migration from v0.11 to v0.12 problem with tags

Tags: terraform

I'm trying migrate my terraform plan from v0.11 to v0.12 terraform version and when I execute the validation I have some error with the same error : "**Unsupported block type**" and the service mark the trouble into the "*TAGS*" tag with that comment:

> Blocks of type "tags" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument "tags"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.

One example it's this troubling resource:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "VPC" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/24"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "true"
  enable_dns_support   = "true"

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.name}-VPC-Default"
    Environment = var.env
    Region      = var.region
  }
}
```

I read into the documentation about this resource that support tag type "*TAGS*" and into the v0.11 version it's working fine.

Any suggestion about what it's my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is explaining that in Terraform 0.12 `tags` are no longer a block, but rather now an argument. A block in Terraform appears like:

```
block { ... }
```

which is how your tags currently appear. An argument appears like:

```
argument = value
```

Therefore, you need to convert your `tags` from a block to an argument. That can be done like the following:

```
tags = {
  Name        = "${var.name}-VPC-Default"
  Environment = var.env
  Region      = var.region
}
```

where `tags` is now being assigned the `map` value you formerly contained within your block.

Comment: There's more context on this in the Terraform 0.12 upgrade guide: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#attributes-vs-blocks